# Python Hotkey: Multiple outputs with just one press of the hotkey

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, hotkeys

I have encountered a problem with about Hotkeys in Python. Thank you for your reading and hope to get help.

1. Context(Goal of the code): Press "p" on the keyboard to print "over p" for one time, press "e" to print "over e" for one time.
2. Problem: The output repeats many times with just one press and seems to have somthing to do with the variable 'i' .
3. Code:

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard

def test_p():
    print('over p')
def test_e():
    print('over e')
    
for i in range(4):
    print(f'circle No.{i}')
    sleep(2)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('p', test_p)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('e', test_e)
    print(f'later')
```

4. Outputs：
   I tried to press p or e and got this results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPqBv.png)

when I run the code again, the outputs became more confusing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO4PZ.png)